# How to change the background image when using the Unity Facebook SDK

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm using the Unity Facebook SDK to set up my Unity game in Facebook.

I've setup the app using 'Unity integration enabled' and the game works as desired.

I would like to change the background image of the webpage from plain white to a bitmap image.

I would normally edit the HTML to do this but I don't have access to it through the SDK.

I've tried using Application.ExternalEval to inject some Javascript into the HTML page similar to this:

```
var content = document.getElementById("pagelet_canvas_content");
content.style.backgroundImage = "url('background.jpg')";
```

But I can't access any of the elements that the Chrome debugger is telling me are there.

Does anyone know how to personalise the Facebook page?

Answer (score 1):

pagelet_canvas_content is in the parent frame which you don't have control over. Your game runs in an iframe. Try grabbing the body element and modifying that.

```
$('body').css('backgroundImage', 'url(background.jpg)');
```

(or use document.getElementsByTagName('body') etc.)

You may also want to set the canvas width and height to fluid to fill the space inside the facebook chrome, and then you may want to center the player (this functionality is coming to the SDK soon, so you shouldn't have to mess with any of this in the future).

Let me know if you have any problems, thanks for trying the SDK!

Answer (score 0):

This is some code to center and resize the unity webplayer on a window resize. You could easily add javascript to load a background.  This is injected once the unity app loads via Application.ExternalEval.

```
window.onresize = function (){
var div = document.getElementById('unityPlayerEmbed');
if ((div.parentNode.offsetHeight+offset)>div.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.clientHeight){
    div.style.height=(div.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.clientHeight-offset)+'px';
    div.parentNode.style.height=div.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.clientHeight+'px';
    div.parentNode.style.width=(div.parentNode.offsetHeight*1.777)+'px';
}else{
    div.parentNode.style.width='100%';
    div.style.height=((div.parentNode.offsetWidth*0.5625)-offset)+'px';
    div.parentNode.style.height=(div.parentNode.offsetWidth*0.5625)+'px';
}
```